# Better understanding of Simplex Noise

Tags: image-processing, textures, procedural-programming, procedural-generation

Well it's needless to say that I've recently found simplex noise. The algorithm for an absolute different amount of possibilities and so on which is great for creating textures, height maps and time-dependent graphics.

I already have the function in the program and it works wonders, the problem is that as a "mathematician" I just can't stand not understanding thoroughly how the function works.

Basically the only thing I don't really understand is if the "skewed" coordinates are the coordinates of the simplical or orthogonal grid. And also that if the inputs define which of these grids: the simplical or orthogonal.

I'm certain I could figure the rest out but I just don't understand which grid belongs to which coordinates. Also any video, book, link that at least shows a visual step-by-step process would be very useful.

Note:

If a questions or doubt arises please leave a comment. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old almost, but in case someone has similar issues.

The coordinates begin as simplical and then are skewed to the orthogonal plane.  They are then skewed back. The math behind it can be a bit tricky. I had similar problems until I got this helpful reply from a redditor in /r/math.

http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/279yzt/guidance_on_simplex_noise/